# Django using Jquery to POST data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, for-loop

Im designing an app where you have connections and a list of pending connection requests are loaded on the side of the page. The issue I am having is writing a jQuery function to accept the request and refresh the div box on the page. I cannot figure out how to pass the id of the connection request to my jquery function which would then pass that id to my view for manipulation of the assoiciated object.

Here is my JS code:

```
function accept(id) {
  $.post("/accept/", function(json){
  alert("Was successful?: " + json['success']);
});

function addClickHandlers() {
  $("#accept").click( function() { accept(id) });
}
$(document).ready(accept);
```

Here is the html I am trying to make call the JS:

```
      <table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <tbody>
      {% for request in conReqs %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.creator.username }}<a onclick="accept({{ request.id }});">Accept</a> &middot; <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i> <a href="#">Hide</a></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

When I click accept nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `onlick` attribute, just attach the event handler unobtrusively with jQuery. You also shouldn't have nested `<a>` tags.

```
function accept( id ) {

  $.post( "/accept/", function ( json ) {

    alert( "Was successful?: " + json[ 'success' ] );

  } );

}


function addClickHandlers() {

  $( ".accept" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    accept( /\d+$/.exec( event.target.id )[0] );

  } );

}


$( document ).ready( function () {

  addClickHandlers();

  // If you really mean to call this at this point:
  accept();

} );


<table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <tbody>
    {% for request in conReqs %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#{{ request.id }}" class="accept"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.creator.username }}Accept</a> &middot; <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i> <a href="#">Hide</a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Event Handling

HTML:

```
<a href="" id="some-link">Some link</a>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  // Select element(s). In this case, the one element with the ID
  // "some-link". Call `on()` on the selected elements to register an
  // event listener, in this case for the `click` event. The second
  // argument to `on()` is the handler function, which will be called
  // when the event occurs and will be passed a jQuery Event object.

  $( "#some-link" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

    // This prevents the default action associated with the event on
    // the target element. In the case of a click event on an
    // `a[href]` element, the default action would be to load the URL
    // that the `href` resolves to.

    event.preventDefault();

    // One of the properties of the Event object is `target` -- the
    // element that the event occured on. In this case the target will
    // be an `a[href]` element, so I can read `event.target.href`. If
    // the `a` element had nested elements, `event.target` could be
    // the nested element. In that case, you could do
    // `$( event.target ).closest( "a" )` to make sure you get the `a`
    // element that the event occured within.

    // Here I'm running a regular expression on `event.target.href` to
    // get a sequence of digits at the end.

    var id = /\d+$/.exec( event.target.href )[0];

  } );

} );
```

For the use case in your question, the code could be condensed down to something like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  $( ".accept" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = /\d+$/.exec( event.target.href )[0]; 

    $.post( "/accept/", { id : id }, function ( json ) {

      // ...

    } );

  } );

} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get an error though on  accept( /\d+$/.exec( event.target.id )[0] ); saying that
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null :8000/:43
(anonymous function) :8000/:43
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3332
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

Comment: I'd do `console.log( event.target.id )` before that line and see what you have.  Did you setup the HTML like I suggested -- `<a href="#{{ request.id }}" class="accept">`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake obviously. I put the wrong attribute in the code: `id` when it should be `href`. I updated the code to correct that. I hadn't gotten that far with your original code yet, but as @dm03514 pointed out you obviously need to send the necessary data to the server, so if that ends up being the most key thing obviously his answer should be accepted over mine, but I still recommend you incorporate the suggestions from mine -- don't nest `<a>` tags and attach the event handlers unobtrusively.

Comment: Both of you deserved the answer but without your code structure and logic I wouldnt have gotten anywhere even with fixing post. Im kind of confused how event works and I would appreciate an explanation so I know how to implement something similar in the future.

Comment: Ok. @dm03514 would probably like it if you left them a comment mentioning how their answer was helpful. I added a section to my answer about how the event handling works in general. Not sure if you have a specific question about it. Also, if you post a comment here showing what data you're passing to `$.post()`, I'll put that in my answer to make it more complete for the benefit of anyone looking at this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was just confused about how the event was being handled. Everything makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually posting any data.  When debugging javascript make sure a console is open,  This will show all syntax errors and requests.  It is important to learn how to debug code.  Use `console.log` liberally to find out what part of your code is executing and what is not executing.

You can post data passing a object with data after the url

```
var postData = {'id': id};
 $.post("/accept/", postData, function(json){
```

In your django view you can access the id by

`request.POST.get('id')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Its my first time doing javascript so I'm a pretty big noob when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: are you on firefox? if so firebug is absolutely necessary! if you're on chrome you can right click and 'inspect element' this will bring up console. console.log lets you "print" to the console.  So `console.log('here')` will show up 'here' in the console tab.

Comment: Yeah I am on Chrome and I've used inspect element for html debugging before but never for JS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I wouldn't have been able to finish my algorithm with out it but JMM offered the core logic of the JS which was what I really needed so I chose him as answer.